# Set Up Custom Component Type That Using TextInput props and make it work when useRef to the component

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I am creating a custom component, the script is written in TypeScript using React's Hooks

My component will be using some of my typescript type and mix it with TextInput type (so i can access TextInput props)

This is my custom component sample code

```
import { Animated, Platform, TextInput, TextInputProps, View } from 'react-native'

type PropsType = TextInputProps & { //Or should I using TextInput instead of TextInputProps?
    myCustomProp?: string
}

const CustomTextField = (props: PropsType) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            if(props.onSubmitEditing != undefined) {
                props.onSubmitEditing()
            }
        }
    }, [])

    return (
        <View
            style = {{
            }}
        />
    )
}

export default CustomTextField
```

Then I import it on my screen and display it like this

```
<CustomTextField
    placeholder = 'Password'
    ref = {passwordInput}
    secureTextEntry
/>
```

and this is my ref variable

```
const passwordInput = useRef<typeof CustomTextField>(null)
```

but the typescript give me error when ref to the component

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From docs, **You may not use the ref attribute on function components** because they don’t have instances.

But in recent times, functional components have become popular because of hooks and everything, React has introduced `forwardRef`.

so your child component code should be of

```
export default React.forwardRef((props: CustomProps, ref) => {
  // All other existing code
});
```

in the parent component,

```
const passwordInput = useRef<CustomTextField>(null)

<CustomTextField
    placeholder='Password'
    ref={passwordInput}
    secureTextEntry
/>
```

Comment: massive thanks for the answer, I end up change it to class component

Comment: this doesn't seem to be doing it for me... I get the following error: 

`'CustomTextInput' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof CustomTextInput'?`